# Testing exceptions in Dart

Tags: dart, mockito-dart

When writing tests around code that will throw an exception, how can Dart/Mockito(or anything else) avoid throwing a real exception?
For example, these tests should both pass and detect the thrown exception - but Dart throws a real exception in the 1st test so only 'It receives a Todo' passes.

```
void main() {
  test('It throws an exception', () async {
    final client = MockClient();
    when(client.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))).thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('', 404));
    expect(await fetchTodo(client, 1), throwsException);
  });

  test('It receives a Todo', () async {
    final client = MockClient();
    final jsonString = '''
    {
      "id": 1,
      "userId": 1,
      "title": "test",
      "completed": false
    }
    ''';
    when(client.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2'))).thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response(jsonString, 200));
    expect(await fetchTodo(client, 2), isA<Todo>());
  });
}
```

and the mocked get method(based on mockito's generated code - I get the same results when using `@GenerateMocks([http.Client])` in my test file.

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {
  Future<http.Response> get(Uri url, {Map<String, String>? headers}) {
    return super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#get, [url], {#headers: headers}), returnValue: Future.value(http.Response('', 200))) as Future<http.Response>;
  }
}
```

```
class Todo {
  int id;
  int userId;
  String title;
  bool completed;

  Todo(this.id, this.userId, this.title, this.completed);
}

Future<Todo> fetchTodo(http.Client client, int id) async {
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$id'));

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Todo(1, 1, 'Test', true);
  }else {
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch resource');
  }
}
```

Test run report:

```
00:00 +0: It throws an exception
00:00 +0 -1: It throws an exception [E]
  Exception: Failed to fetch resource
  test/test.dart 49:5  fetchTodo
  
00:00 +0 -1: It receives a Todo
00:00 +1 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you do:

> ```
> expect(await fetchTodo(client, 1), throwsException);
> ```

`expect()` is a normal function, and function arguments are evaluated before the function is invoked. (Dart is an *applicative-order* language.) You therefore are waiting for `fetchTodo` to complete *before* calling `expect()` (and before `expect` can try to match against the `throwsException` `Matcher`).

As explained by the [`throwsA`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/throwsA.html) documentation (and this applies to the `throwsException` `Matcher` too), it must be matched against a zero-argument function or a `Future`.  You do not need to (and should not) `await` the call to `fetchTodo`.

Also, since you're calling an asynchronous function, the expectation cannot be checked synchronously, so you'll also need to use `expectLater` instead of `expect`:

```dart
await expectLater(fetchTodo(client, 1), throwsException);
```