# How do I make a conditional mockito response?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have this piece of code mocking a response:

(isFirstSubmit is initialized to true)

```
     when(
      mockProfileRepository.submitProfile(
        localNumber: localNumber,
        profileContactInfo: fakeProfileContactInfo.copyWith(
          email: modifiedEmail,
          phone: modifiedPhone,
        ),
      ),
    ).thenAnswer((_) async {
      if (isFirstSubmit) {
        debugPrint('Saving profile first time');
        isFirstSubmit = false;
        throw OrderInProgressException();
      } else {
        debugPrint('Saving profile...');
        return Future.value(true);
      }
    });
```

However the throw OrderInProgressException makes the test abort instead of being part of the equation...

So what I want (just to be clear) is to mock returning an OrderInProgressException (which the submitProfile method would) first time and a Future.value(true) the second time.

How can I mock a condition like this?

Comment: It's unclear what you intend to do.  Why are you throwing the exception?  What is supposed to catch it?

Comment: @jamesdlin Better now?

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem with the mock?  If your mock is mimicking the behavior of the real function by throwing an exception, then if that causes your test to fail, that's a problem with your test, not with your mock.  Your test needs to expect the exception.  Perhaps see [Testing exceptions in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66324460/).